Dynamic routing in angular based on a condition
I want my app to route to different components based on an environment variable(e.g. switch). In the constructor of  app routing module , I have added the condition to check for the variable.
if(switch === 'ON'){
    router.resetConfig(route1);
 }
else if(switch === 'OFF'){
   router.resetConfig(route2);
 }

In the ngDoBootstrap method of AppModule, I am calling the backend to get the value of environment variable.
Now the problem is, when I load the app for the first time, constructor of app routing module is getting called first and then the backend call is happening.
I want to wait for the backend call to fetch the value of switch and then execute the condition written in the constructor.
However, after refreshing the page again, it routes to the correct path.
I tried setting timeout in the constructor, It works but that is not the correct way though.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

You need to use APP_INITIALIZER to perform the configuration before the application loads.
import { APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { take } from 'rxjs';

...

...

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      multi: true,
      useFactory: (http: HttpService, router: Router) => {
        return () => http.get('/api-route').pipe(
                         take(1),
                         tap((data) => {
                              if(switch === 'ON'){
                                  router.resetConfig(route1);
                              } else if(switch === 'OFF'){
                                  router.resetConfig(route2);
                              }
                         })
                     );
      },
      deps: [HttpService, Router],
    },
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}

Reference Article

Thanks for the reply. I tried this  but again the value of switch is null at this point.

@Teeee replace switch with data typo from my side

ok and this '/api-route' should be the api call to backend?

@Teeee yes, we read this response and perform the logic

Sure, unable to upvote though as I am a new contributor.
